# openMP initialization of the iterator in the for loop with curly braces

Tags: c++, openmp

I have this main :

```
int main() {

    std::size_t n{10000};
    std::vector<int> A(n);

    for (size_t k{0}; k < 10000; ++k) { // repeating the same task over and over again.
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
        {
#pragma omp for    
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                A[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following problem, the initialization with the list initializer (curly braces) does not work :

this works

```
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            A[i] = i;
        }
```

this doesn't

```
        for (size_t i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
            A[i] = i;
        }
```

do you have any idea why ? I have been told one should always initialize with curly braces, instead of `=` or normal braces `( )`.

---

I use MinGW, on CLion and I fixed my CMake regarding OpenMP as:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

Comment: Which compiler and which compiler options are you using? (e.g. g++ -std=c++17 ...)

Comment: @Damien I updated the answer regarding the compiler options. Is it enough information?

Comment: Yes. Effectively, I got the same compilation error when compiling with gcc and option `-fopenmp`, up to C++17. No issue without this option (but no MP in this case!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OpenMP 5.0 API](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) doesn't allow the following construct:

```
#pragma omp for    
    for (size_t i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
        A[i] = i;
    }
```

Section 2.9.2 says:

> The `for` directive places restrictions on the structure of all associated `for`-loops. Specifically, all associated `for`-loops must have *canonical loop* form(see Section 2.9.1 on page 95).

And section 2.9.1 says:

> The loops associated with a loop-associated directive have *canonical loop form* if they conform to the following:
>
> ```
> ----------------
> for (init-expr;test-expr;incr-expr) structured-block
> ----------------
> init-expr One of the following:
>           var=lb
>           integer-type var=lb
>           random-access-iterator-type var=lb
>           pointer-type var=lb
> ```

There is no grammar rule that applies to `size_t i{0}`, and so the code is not conforming.  Range-for loops also have canonical form, but that doesn't apply here.